# How to compute sample variance from sample moments

Tags: statistics

Given $X_1, \dots , X_n$ i.i.d. and the two sample moments 
$$M_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i = \bar{X}$$
and $$ M_2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i^2$$
how can I compute:
$$ S^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X})^2$$ 
such as:
$$S^2 = f(M_1, M_2)$$

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: This has nothing to do with statistics and could have been tagged (algebra) or (polynomials).

Comment: ok, got it. Thank you did.

Comment: This has to do with statistics in that the derived formula is commonly used for computing the variance estiamte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - M_1)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2 - 2 X_i M_1 + M_1^2) =$

$= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - 2 M_1 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n M_1^2 =$

$= M_2 - 2M_1^2 + M_1^2 = M_2 - M_1^2$